# Laptop battery not charging after very long storage

Tags: battery, power

A new laptop manufactured 4+ years ago and never used since then.
It has an internal battery that was not detached during the whole storage time.

The battery cannot be charged even after official reset procedure (via pinhole at the bottom of the laptop, holding "Power On" button for some time etc.) and after being on charger for several hours. Windows reports that battery is present, but it's 0%, plugged in, not charging.

BatteryInfoView utility (and other similar diagnostic software) reports this:

> Battery Name: AC14B3K
>
> Manufacture Name: SANYO
>
> Serial Number: 2699
>
> Power State: Critical, AC Power
>
> Current Capacity (in %): 0.0%
>
> Full Charged Capacity: 51,051 mWh
>
> Designed Capacity: 51,051 mWh
>
> Battery Health: 100.0%
>
> Voltage: 4,557 millivolts
>
> Charge/Discharge Rate: 0 milliwatts
>
> Chemistry: Lithium Ion
>
> Low Battery Capacity (1): 2,787 mWh
>
> Low Battery Capacity (2): 3,557 mWh
>
> Number of charge/discharge cycles: 0

So, I assume the battery discharged so much that it cannot start charging for some reason.

Is there any way to refresh/revive the battery, so it starts charging?  Or is it an irreversible degradation of cells and I need to get a new battery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your rechargeable battery is assumably LiIo-based.
Once the voltage of those batteries is sinking below 2,5V there is a risk of internal destruction by short-circuit.

Battery manufacturers combine cells in series and in parallel.
You should disclose the nominal voltage of the battery in question because it enables you to figure out the number of cells in series.
If there are 3 cells in series, the total voltage should be at least 3x2,5V.
Your 4,6V suggests lasting dammage to your battery.
I guess 2 cells in series is less probable.
I would replace this battery if possible.

Comment: Looking up the battery part number it looks like it has 4 pouch type cells in series and a 15.2V nominal voltage

Comment: Yup. If a cell is below 2.5V for more than a brief period, or has fallen below 2.0V, it's probably not going to be safe to use.

Answer (score 1):

You need a specialist charger to attempt to revive it.
Take it to a professional, don't attempt to do this yourself.

When a Li-ion battery goes into a deep discharge state, protection circuitry kicks in to actually prevent it being recharged.

Pushing a large amount of power into it will kick start it if it's ever going to happen - however, this is potentially highly dangerous & should never be attempted without the correct equipment; which will sense if the battery is not performing correctly. Copper build-up internally could cause short-circuits.

See: [Battery University: How to Awaken a Sleeping Li-ion](https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/low_voltage_cut_off)